# How to return unsorted items from within a sort function?

Tags: javascript, sorting

I'm filtering and sorting items in this fashion:

```
items
  .filter(// filter logic)
  .sort((a, b) => {
    if (shouldntSort) return
    // sorting logic
  },
```

I thought the `return` would stop the `sort` function but I was wrong. Only removing the whole `.sort` method stops the items from beign sorted.

How do I return the unsorted items form within `.sort?`

Comment: *"How do I return the unsorted items form within .sort?"* What does that mean? If you don't want them sorted, don't sort them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you call `sort`, you're going to sort. There's no reasonable way not to.

So don't call `sort` in the case where you don't want to sort:

```
items = items.filter(/*...*/);
if (!shouldntSort) {
    items.sort();
}
```

> I thought the `return` would stop the `sort` function

The `return` just exits the sort callback. `sort` calls the callback repeatedly to ask how two items should relate to one another (whether the first should be before or after the second). There's no "cancel the sort" return value from that callback.

---

If you needed a version you could use as part of the same expression, you could give yourself a `maybeSort` function:

```
Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, "maybeSort", {
    value: function(shouldSort, sortCallback) {
        if (shouldSort) {
            return sortCallback ? this.sort(sortCallback) : this.sort();
        }
        return this;
    }
});
```

then

```
items = items
    .filter(/*...*/)
    .maybeSort(!shouldntSort);
```